# I'm completely lost in this hangman game

Tags: java, project

So I have this project and I'm currently stuck in the "guessLetter" part of the code.

```
public boolean guessLetter( String letter ) {
    /* If the letter has already been guessed, print out a message that
     * it's already been guessed and return true.
     */
    letter = letter.toUpperCase();
    for(int x = 0; x<letter.length(); x++){
        String a = letter.substring(x, x+1);
        if(letter.equals(a)){
            System.out.println("This letter was already found");
        }
    }

    /* Check to see if the letter is in phrase. If it is, put it into
     * solved in the correct place, replacing the underscore. 
     */
    for(int y = 0; y<letter.length(); y++){
        String blank = " ";
        String b = letter.substring(y, y+1);

        return true;
    }



    /* Fix this so it returns the right value, every time */
    return false;

}
```

As you can see I've been trying stuff but I think that my current code doesn't work at all, and it's obvious that I haven't finished.

If you could explain what I have wrong, and why, I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: "_I think that my current code doesn't work at all_" Why do you think that? What is it supposed to do and what is it actually doing? If you are not sure if it works or not how are we supposed to correct it?

Comment: What’s the error? Is `letter` only one character long and therefore your loops won’t run? If `letter` is supposed to be the full word, then you’re variable names are misleading.

Comment: It looks like you're checking `letter` against itself. Shouldn't you be checking against the word or phrase, and then adding the letter to a guessed letters container?

Comment: On the comment _"Check to see if the letter is in phrase."_ but there no conditional on the loop. If `letter.length()` is greater than 0 the function will always return true.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what's being asked here. It is ambiguous, vague, overly broad, incomplete or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current state.

Answer (score -1):

I love doing homework :-)

This should get you started.

```
public class HangMan {
    HashSet<String> guessedLetters = new HashSet();
    String phrase = "myWord";

    public boolean guessLetter(String letter) {
        if (guessedLetters.contains(letter)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            guessedLetters.add(letter);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void inPhrase(String letter) {
        if (phrase.contains(letter)) {
            // Get all index of letter
            int index = phrase.indexOf(letter);
            while (index >= 0) {         
                index = phrase.indexOf(letter, index + 1);
                // Show the letter at this index
            }
        } else {
            // Decrease the number of guesses till zero, then update hangman?
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: (Unrelated, but inPhrase seems quite redundant-it's a one-liner.)

Comment: He will probably need to do additional logic in inPhrase, like update his UI etc.